# Getting set up with git and grunt

Tags: git, gruntjs

I am the current sole developer of a content management system used by Toastmasters public speaking clubs worldwide to produce free websites for those clubs.  This is an independent effort using open source libraries/tools and volunteer labor--I am not a professional developer and I work on this in my spare time.  When I took over the development of the system, it was a mess: multiple code versions in individual files, no file versions, terrible code organization, and no development tools to speak of.  I have improved on that somewhat, but I want to take it to the next level to allow for bringing in other developers.  The code is Perl, MySQL, and JavaScript (w/ jQuery, jQuery UI).  I considered putting the code on GitHub, but I want to get it better organized before I release it to public scrutiny.  I have remote server access via PuTTY and FTP for uploading code updates.  I have installed git, node.js, grunt, bower, and less on the server (Amazon Web Services), along with a number of the grunt plugins--I have zero experience with any of these.  What I want is to maintain 3 parallel versions of the code: production, production duplicate (for bug fix testing), and development code.  I will also be implementing language translation support which I will need versioning for, also.

Frankly, I am at a bit of a loss about where to start.  I am not sure if I should work on organization of the git code repository or if I should focus on getting grunt going for me first.  Any insights or recommendations are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at this link for a GIT release strategy, as it sounds like you are going to need to use branching for your different code environments.

http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

In terms of using Grunt, this is a good idea to automate certain tasks, like minification, pre-processing, and such.  You can also configure different tasks to run on certain environments using grunt-env.

https://github.com/jsoverson/grunt-env

If you would also like to use GIT but not make the the code public, you sign up for a free account on BitBucket, which is free GIT private hosting.  It's probably best you do this now and get started with maintaining your code base here for backup purposes and code tracking.

So in my opinion, get started with GIT first, then start integration Grunt using git to manage your new code.

https://bitbucket.org/

Comment: So, I looked over the information you provided.  Regarding git, I have it installed on our server.  Are you suggesting that I should be doing git via BitBucket instead of via PuTTY into our server?  I am uncertain how I would transfer the code to/from BitBucket to our server for use.  Also, given that I only have the one server to work with, the released code, development code, and bugfix code versions all reside on the same server.  (I have no choice with that.)

Comment: I have an index.cgi file that detects special ip addresses (e.g., mine) and loads the appropriate html/js/css/perl etc.  Given that, I am uncertain how I migrate to a git-based approach, since it seems like I can only have one code version from git "active"/in-use at a given time.   I need to be able to do development work on the same server as the released code is running on.  I understand that its probably not the most risk-aware approach, but it is what I have to work with.